# How to get a YTM calculation instead of YTD in Google Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio, business-intelligence

I have an earnings table in my Google Data Studio report from January 21 - YTD.

But what i want is a table that shows me YTM (so this year until last month) Jan-21 til Sep-21 and that dynamicly on 1st Nov, Okt-21 is added to the table, and on 1st dec Nov-21
is added etc.

Because the Total YTD value is other wise too high, due to cost being booked at the end of the month and earnings through the month.

Filters wont let you do it dynamicly,
date range filters same,
always possible to do it manualy with date range but this i cannot ask from my client.

any suggestions??

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer,

i left the question for when someone else wants to do it,

it is actualy simpel fixed by using advanced date filter and then leaving the start date on 1-jan, and end date to today  minus 1 month.

this gave me the exact result i needed yt last month